# semantic-ui-react Content goes under the menu when it's stackable

Tags: css, reactjs, jsx, semantic-ui-react

I have a *main* component

```
return (
    <>
      <NavBar />
      <Container style={{marginTop: '7em'}}>
        <List>
          {accounts.map(account => (
            <List.Item key={account.id}>
              {account.id}
            </List.Item>
          ))}
        </List>
      </Container>
    </>
  );
```

That contains a *NavBar*

```
import React from 'react';
import { Container, Icon, Menu } from 'semantic-ui-react';

export default function NavBar() {
    return (
        <Menu inverted fixed='top' stackable>
            <Container>
                <Menu.Item header>
                    <Icon name='chess pawn' size='large' />
                    Menu 1
                </Menu.Item>
                <Menu.Item name='Menu 2' />
                <Menu.Item name='Menu 3' />
                <Menu.Item name='Menu 4' />
                <Menu.Item name='Menu 5' />
            </Container>
        </Menu>
    )
}
```

This looks alright on desktop

[image]

but on mobile resolutions when the Menu stacks and some content goes behind it.

[image]

Is there any elegant way to address this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In semantic-ui, when using `fixed='top'` on `Menu`, it is taken out of the flow of document due to `position: fixed`, which allows other content to go under it.

It is also the reason why a higher `marginTop` was needed on the content `container` to create some space on top.

Instead of `fixed='top'`, try use a custom class (or inline style) for `NavBar` to apply `position: sticky` on it, so it is placed considering the flow but still stays in view as the window scrolls.

More about [`position: sticky`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

Live demo of the minimized example: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-hvd9mp?file=src/App.js)

Example:

```
.custom-nav {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

Add the `className` to `NavBar`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Container, Icon, Menu } from 'semantic-ui-react';

export default function NavBar() {
    return (
        <Menu inverted stackable className="custom-nav">
            <Container>
                <Menu.Item header>
                    <Icon name='chess pawn' size='large' />
                    Menu 1
                </Menu.Item>
                <Menu.Item name='Menu 2' />
                <Menu.Item name='Menu 3' />
                <Menu.Item name='Menu 4' />
                <Menu.Item name='Menu 5' />
            </Container>
        </Menu>
    )
}
```

Alternatively, perhaps a [sticky](https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/sticky/) component by semantic-ui can be used to wrap `NavBar` for the same result, although it seems that it would result in an additional wrapper in the structure.

Hope this will help.